# FFMPEG - Convert png's to video files

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I have ~10k PNG-Files that I would like to convert into a video.

From [looking around the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299196/how-to-write-frames-to-a-video-file) I came across ffmpeg and chose to run the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -i img/* -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 video.mp4
```

First of all, running this command yielded the prompt `File 'img/00001.png' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]`, which seems a little strange to me since, as far as I understand, the command should not modify the images themselves, just create a new `video.mp4` file?

Anyhow, I didn't want to press `y` 10k times, so I backed up my images and  modified the command:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -i img/* -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 -y video.mp4
```

Now, the program seems to run fine for 254 images but then throws the error:

```
[png @ 0x7facf0503800] ff_frame_thread_encoder_init failed
Error initializing output stream 255:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #255:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

In case it's useful, I added the [full log file here](http://www.bankosegger.at/misc/ffmpeg_log.txt). And, for good measure, [here is an example from the images](http://www.bankosegger.at/misc/00093.png) I want to convert. Also, [here is the infamous frame 255](http://www.bankosegger.at/misc/00255.png), on which the program crashes.

Comment: Looking a little closer at the log file, it seems like it is mapping one input to 10k outputs. That doesn't quite make sense. Does it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ffmpeg requires each input file to have its own `-i` argument, so when you run `-i img/*`, your shell will expand the wildcard to a series of images, which ffmpeg will in turn read as only *one* input image, but 10k (minus one) output images. In other words, ffmpeg will see:

```
ffmpeg … -i img/00000.png img/00001.png …
```

which is telling it to use `00000.png` as input and `00001.png` as output. 
In fact, you will have overwritten all your files `00001.png` through `00254.png`  with the content of `00000.png`. So I hope you have a backup of those.

Once you've restored your original input files, please check your command again. You haven't used the `%d` wildcard to specify image numbers (which was shown in the linked answer). So, use:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 25 -i img/%05d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 video.mp4
```

For more info, check the [Slideshow guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow). There you'll also find different options for specifying the list of input files (e.g. through a glob pattern, similar to what you were attempting to do).

Comment: Thanks! That makes so much more sense! Should've followed the original instructions more closely - d'oh!
Yeah, all the files were backed up :)

Answer (score 2):

You ***can*** also use asterisk wildcards, but the file list needs to be quoted to prevent the expansion as per the answer of **@slhck**, and you need an extra option `pattern_type` to tell it to use globbing.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -pattern_type glob -i 'img/*.png' -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 video.mp4
```